# Changing a cell's value based on formatting

Tags: excel

I receive a `monthly spreadsheet` from another team whose data I need to import to a database.  A cell may have a value like `98.772535%`, which the other team has displayed as `98.8%` via cell formatting.  The number that I need to import is the `98.8%`, however when I go to import the `database` takes the actual cell value, necessitating a `line-by-line` audit.

Is there a simple way to change the value in multiple cells to match the numbers that are displayed?

Comment: With VBA - loop through the range and make each cell's `.Value` equal to its `.Text`...

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you!